# 'Authentication failed, please try again' on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nomachine

I have a weird problem when I want to change settings in NoMachine.

I get the error: `Authentication failed, please try again.`

https://share.cleanshot.com/C4lnTBKn

My password is working in the terminal, etc. On the second machine, I have the same configuration and don't have this error. I have researched the forum and the internet, trying different approaches like:

- https://forum.nomachine.com/topic/authentication-failing-when-unlocking-to-change-server-preferences
- https://loggedfixes.com/tech/software/linux-apps/cant-login-to-nomachine-but-logins-are-correct-error-authentication-failed-please-try-again/
- https://forum.nomachine.com/topic/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-authentication-failed-when-asked-for-admin-password

But I still get the same error. I have tried rebooting, restarting, and reinstalling NoMachine. Additionally, I noticed that I must log out with my Ubuntu by VNC when I connect with NoMachine, or else I get an extended desktop. Below is a step-by-step guide for how I installed NoMachine on my Ubuntu:

- I installed Ubuntu Server minimal, and then:

```
# 1. Update your package lists

sudo apt update

# 2. Install LXQt

sudo apt install lxqt

# 3. Install Xorg (if not installed)

sudo apt install xorg

# 4. Download NoMachine package

wget https://download.nomachine.com/download/8.5/Linux/nomachine_8.5.3_1_amd64.deb

# 5. Install NoMachine package

sudo dpkg -i nomachine_8.5.3_1_amd64.deb

# 6. Fix missing dependencies

sudo apt -f install
```